# BCNF Decomposition (Database Design)

Tags: database-design, normalization, decomposition

I'm trying to decompose several tables into BCNF. I believe the first one is decomposed correctly, but I'm unsure whether or not the others can be decomposed. Any help is appreciated

```
**make(id, name, est, founder, city, state)**

id->name;
name->est, city, state, founder;
city->state

New Relations: [Key(id),name], [Key(name),est,city,state,founder], [Key(city),state]

**model(id, makeId, name, year, category)**

id->makeId, name;
name->year, category (not superkey, but can't really decompose)

**features(id, modelId, abs, tpms, sidebags, drl)**

id->modelID, abs, tpms, sidebags, drl 

**user(id, name, pass, first, last, phone, isAdmin)**

id->name, pass, isAdmin; name->first, last, phone

**selling(id, price, modelId, mileage, userId)**

id->price, modelId, mileage, userID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCNF is easy: just make sure all dependencies between attribute sets in a single relation are dependencies on a superkey of the relation. Your first one is close, but the second relation needs to omit "state". Often, people stop at 3NF since not all relations with FDs have dependency-preserving BCNF decompositions. Do you need help decomposing the other relations? I will help, if you need it.

Edit: Help on other relations.

Selling and Features are fine. Models and Users need to be split on Name in order to be in BCNF; you indicate this isn't something you can do for Models. Why? Name implies the stuff on the right of the arrow, right?

Comment: Yes, if you could help me decompose the others it would be much appreciated. I'm still learning how to apply the algorithm, so to see how to do it in those cases would be a big help.

Comment: THE lhs has to be a superkey, right? If I broke it up like:  [Key(id),makeId, name] [Key(name), year, category] would it be correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Keep name in the first, yes. The dependency within any given relation has to be on a superkey of that relation; that superkey doesn't have to be a superkey of the original. The decomposition you suggest in the comment above is a correct, dependency-preserving, lossless BCNF decomposition.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'm assuming the users table is decomposed as follows: R1: [Key(id), name, pass, isAdmin]
R2: [Key(name), first, last, phone]   Will these new relations satisfy BNCF like the new model relations? Can selling/features be considered already in BCNF?